# Start & Stop internet connexion without broking Network Manager

Tags: networking, command-line, network-manager

I am on Precise.
I used this command (with an alias), to close the network,

> dbus-send --system --print-reply --reply-timeout=120000 --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager stop

it worked, now I have to use

> dbus-send --system --print-reply --reply-timeout=120000 --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Sleep boolean:true

it work but not so well, sometimes I can't restart the network and NetworkManager is blocked too and strange errors even GUI freeze .
 What I need is a command line which close the network and don't mess with Network Manager, maybe with the routing table or what else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be looking at `nmcli` for toggling network connectivity. You can do that globally through:

```
nmcli n enable false  # turns it all off
nmcli n enable true   # turns it all back on
```

Comment: Big thank, I couldn't dream of a so direct, perfect and simple solution.

Comment: It learn me that the good command was certainly `dbus-send --system --print-reply --reply-timeout=120000 --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Enable boolean:false` .Anyway, nmcli even better.